# Composer Google API on PHP

Tags: php, composer-php

Good day,i tried to install `google/apiclient` in my `composer.json`

```
{
  "require": {
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"
  }
}
```

But when I start the installing it asks me for username and password. For this I use my count of `github.com`  and `packagist.org` but, always I get this message:

> ```
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
>     Authentication required (packagist.org):
>       Username: camilosama
>       Password:
>
>
>   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   Invalid credentials for 'http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013%24b4ff6e388c2
>   ffb38eae7834f1d7454b80e780e4843f445c1ef1354a16ff356c9.json', aborting.
>
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins]  
> [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress]  
> [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]  
> [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
> ```

Comment: From https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/Invalid-credentials-for-https-repo-magento-com-packages-json/td-p/22287 "You should use a public / private keys pair, not email or screenname."

Comment: In this moment i'm change to use my API keys og google api, but it's the same

Comment: Packagist should not ever ask for a password. Are you sure you are not behind a company proxy that needs authentication?